# Braintree - No payment method is available

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, braintree

I'm using Braintree Sandbox and whenever I try to pay I receive an error of DropIn, saying:

> name: "DropinError", message: "No payment method is available.",
> _braintreeWebError: undefined

What have I done to certify myself that everything is alright:

1. Double check the Sandbox Braintree API Credentials
2. Connected Paypal in the "Payment Methods" as asked/required by Braintree Sandbox with the credentials of my App SandBox in Paypal

[image]

The end result in my page, after choosing the Braintree payment method, is:

[image]

It says no payment method is available, yet I can see the "Card" & "Paypal" UI payment methods, but I can't pay with none of them.

I generate the ClientToken in PHP like the following:

```
$gateway = new \Braintree\Gateway(
[
    'merchantId' => env('BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID'),
    'publicKey' => env('BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY'),
    'privateKey' => env('BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY'),
    'environment' => env('BRAINTREE_ENVIRONMENT')
]);

$token = $gateway->clientToken()->generate();
```

And then in Javascript all I do is:

```
// Double checked, its ok!
var token = $('#braintree_token').val();

braintree.dropin.create(
{
    authorization: token,
    container: '#braintree-container',
    paypal:
    {
        flow: 'vault',
    }
}, function(err, instance)
{
    // Error starts after this call
    instance.requestPaymentMethod(function(err, payload)
    {
        // Never reaches here!
        console.log(payload);
    }, 'json');
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think the term "payment method" refers to an already registered card / paypal account. What you see here is referenced as "payment options" according to their docs

Comment: Have you found a solution to the issue?

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this? Everywhere I search for this question, there is no answer. Braintree is either unreliable or the current version is broken and needs rolling back.

Comment: Have you guys found any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

So with my co-worker who was responsible for the FE part ( i was doing BE part ), we encountered the same issue. We struggled a little bit with account configuration but in the end, my friend identified that problem was on the FE part, particularly in requestPaymentMethod. His explanation:

`requestPaymentMethod should be called after the user has selected a payment option, or when he filled in correct credit card details if it’s the only payment option`.
From what I see in your post I see that maybe it is the same mistake.